# Insert current date with time on H2 database

Tags: sql, time, h2

I want to insert the current date with a specific time on my H2 database

***I do this:***

```
INSERT INTO PUBLIC.PROJECT(ID, LIBELLE, DESCRIPTION, STATUT, DATE_CREATION, DATE_MODIFICATION, USER_CREATEUR_ID, REFERENT_ID, DATE_DEBUT, DATE_FIN, TYPE, STATUT_PROJET) VALUES
(25001, 'Projet 1', NULL, 'INITIEE', CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_DATE, NULL, 3, current_date -2 + time '23:00', current_date , NULL, NULL);
```

***I have this error:***

> Impossible danalyser {0} constante {1} Cannot parse {0} constant {1};
>   SQL statement:

What's wrong ?

Comment: H2 probably doesn't support `current_date -2 + time '23:00'`

Answer (score 3):

H2 can parse non-standard time literal `TIME '23:00'` only since version 1.4.198 (note that this is a beta-quality version, use some newer version instead of it).

If you need to use some old version, such as 1.4.197, use standard literal `TIME '23:00:00'`. If you can upgrade, it's better to use use the standard literal anyway.

Please note that the whole construction `current_date -2 + time '23:00'` is weird enough. It can be required for old versions of H2, but if you'll decide to upgrade use the more normal datetime arithmetic with intervals such as `CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '2' DAY + TIME '23:00:00'` instead of this entirely non-standard stuff. Standard-compliant expression should be `CAST(CURRENT_DATE AS TIMESTAMP) - INTERVAL '2' DAY + INTERVAL '23' HOUR`, but it doesn't look nice.